# Calculating total number of calories burned

Tags: java, beginner

The following question was taken from *Absolute Java 5th ed.* by Walter Savitch:

> One way to measure the amount of energy that is expended during
>   exercise is to use metabolic equivalents (MET). Here are some METS for
>   various activities:
>
> - Running 6 MPH: 10 METS
> - Basketball: 8 METS
> - Sleeping: 1 MET
>
> The number of calories burned per minute may be estimated using the
>   following formula: **Calories/Minute= 0.0175 * MET* Weight in
>   kilograms.**
>
> Write a program that calculates and outputs the total number of calories burned for a **150-pound person who runs 6 MPH for 30
>   minutes, plays basketball for 30 minutes, and then sleeps for 6
>   hours**. One kilogram is equal to 2.2 pounds.

This is the code that I have written:

```
public class Question1 {

    final static int RUNNING6MPH = 10;
    final static int BASKETBALL = 8;
    final static int SLEEPING = 1;

    private static double value = 0.0175;
    private static double totalCaloriesBurned = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        totalCaloriesBurned = caloriesPerMinute(RUNNING6MPH, 150, 30)
                + caloriesPerMinute(BASKETBALL, 150, 30)
                + caloriesPerMinute(SLEEPING, 150, hoursToMinutes(6));
        System.out.println(totalCaloriesBurned);
    }

    public static double caloriesPerMinute(int met, double weight, double time) {
        return value * met * poundToKilogram(weight) * time;
    }

    public static double poundToKilogram(double pound) {
        return pound / 2.2;
    }

    public static double hoursToMinutes(double hours) {
        return hours * 60;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, not the most important point but first to grab my attention, [prefer `static final` instead of `final static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219556/difference-between-final-static-and-static-final) in the name of least surprise.

Make everything `private` that can be made `private`, as @maartinus said.

This is a constant so make it `final` also:

```
private static double value = 0.0175;
```

Also name `value` is too generic, use the term from the field if available, you can name it `CALORIES_PER_MET_PER_KG_PER_MINUTE`, or at least `SCALING_FACTOR`.

This is not used anywhere other than `main` therefore should be a local variable there:

```
private static double totalCaloriesBurned = 0;
```

Then you do not need to initialize it to an unused value.

In `main` unnamed constant 150 is used repeatedly. You should name it `weight` or even better `weightInPounds`.

In:

```
public static double caloriesPerMinute(int met, double weight, double time)
```

`caloriesPerMinute` name is wrong, as it does not compute a per minute value. It could be renamed `calories` or `caloriesBurned`.

`double weight, double time` can be named `weightInPounds` and `timeInMinutes` to remind the user to do necessary conversion beforehand.

After renamings I suggested above the formula: `value * met * poundToKilogram(weight) * time` reads:

```
CALORIES_PER_MET_PER_KG_PER_MINUTE * met * poundToKilogram(weightInPounds) * timeInMinutes
```

So that it is easier to verify you did not mess up the units.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK, just a few comments:

For `RUNNING6MPH`, etc., an `enum` seems to be optimal.

I'd recommend to start with all methods `private`. Only when you need them, you review them and then change the visibility.

For the time conversion, there's `TimeUnit`.

Comment: Why use `enum`, though?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Why not? I also do, it nicely groups things, can be extended if needed and also used in `switch`.

Comment: @maaartinus why not is usually not the correct reasoning..

Comment: @Vogel612 That's why I wrote more. But `enum`s are the default for me, whenever more constants of similar kind come together.